# redirect to prod url when creating content

Tags: 7, redirection

I have a Drupal 7 development site that is a subdomain of the production site, eg. dev.prod.com, for example.

When ever I create a content type, new content, a new user, install a new module, etc on the development site it redirects to the production URL after the form is submitted.  I don't have permission on production so I get "access denied". When I go back to the development site and refresh the browser, the content have been created.  But this does not work for installing a module. The module is not installed.  Obviously, this makes it impossible to work on dev.

I have reviewed .htaccess and settings.php for any rewrite rules that could be causing this but I have not found anything.  $base_url is set to the correct URL for the development server. I have cleared the cache many times.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a `$base_url` set in settings.php? https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!globals.php/global/base_url/7.x

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to check the value specified for `$base_url`, within the `settings.php` of your dev.prod.com site. Assign a value of (eg) `dev.prod.com` and see what happens then.

Comment: That's the first thing I tried.  Same problem.  And I cleared the cache multiple times.